# Esconder hora final de um evento no fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

No `FullCalendar` os eventos aparece a hora de inicio e de fim. Haverá forma de mostrar apenas a hora inicial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe a propriedade [displayEventEnd](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventEnd/) ela é responsavel por este controle.

Comment: If some event doesn't show an end date already, for example an element that has only half an hour only show the inicial hour, don't show the start hour.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a linha `timeFormat:'HH:mm',` no

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                    **timeFormat:'HH:mm',**
```